# Set three PATHS in Ubuntu

Tags: environment-variables, ubuntu-12.10

I've been at this all day now, reading every single type of different way to add these lines. It resulted in me being locked out of my profile because I set the .profile wrong. So I'll just ask the very simple question: What do I type in the command shell to get the following to work.

```
Please put /home/karl/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:/home/karl/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix:/home/karl/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix
into your PATH environment; so that you'll be able to run itm/tclsh/wish/xgraph.

IMPORTANT NOTICES:

(1) You MUST put /home/karl/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14, /home/karl/ns-allinone-2.35/lib, 
    into your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.
    If it complains about X libraries, add path to your X libraries 
    into LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
    If you are using csh, you can set it like:
        setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
    If you are using sh, you can set it like:
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=

(2) You MUST put /home/karl/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/library into your TCL_LIBRARY environmental
    variable. Otherwise ns/nam will complain during startup.


After these steps, you can now run the ns validation suite with
cd ns-2.35; ./validate

For trouble shooting, please first read ns problems page 
http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-problems.html. Also search the ns mailing list archive
for related posts.
```

I am supposed to add these to get my .tcl scripts to work as I keep recieving the error

```
**invalid command name "new"
    while executing
"new Simulator"
    invoked from within
"set ns [new Simulator]"
    (file "test.tcl" line 2)**"
Which is a result of my path varibles not being set correctly.
```

What do I type in my default 12.10 terminal to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Running the following commands should set all the requested variables:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/karl/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:/home/karl/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix:/home/karl/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/karl/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14:/home/karl/ns-allinone-2.35/lib
export TCL_LIBRARY=/home/karl/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/library
```

You can either run these commands before running the scripts or add them to your `.profile` or `.bashrc` file to get them automatically run each time you log in.

To ensure that the environment variables get set correctly, use `echo $VARIABLENAME`, e.g. `echo $PATH` after the above commands. The output should contain the new stuff you entered into the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/karl/.local/share/Trash/files/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:/home/karl/.local/share/Trash/files/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix:/home/karl/.local/share/Trash/files/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix
export LD_PATH=$LD_PATH:/home/karl/.local/share/Trash/files/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14:/home/karl/.local/share/Trash/files/ns-allinone-2.35/lib
```

(I have never tried this, but the idea is to add the variables onto the end of your path and make them available to child processes)

Comment: Must I logout and login for this to take affect?

Comment: No - in fact, you will need to run these commands each time you log in to reset them.  (You may be able to fiddle with a .bashrc file or similar to make add them automatically on login)

Comment: Still getting the: "invalid command name "new"
    while executing
"new Simulator"
    invoked from within
"set ns [new Simulator]"
    (file "test.tcl" line 2)" issue :/ I looked this issue up, and it has to do with the otcl package not being found

Comment: EDIT: I updated the question as my files where located in the rubbish bin, they are now where they are supposed to be, however still no luck  with your commands :/